# replace only the last match of preg string with preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

just the the images

```
$content="}
}
hello world
          }
}"
$text='}\s*[\r\n]*\s*[\r\n]*\s*}';
$ss="~$text(?!.*$text)~";
$res=preg_replace($ss,'replacement',content);
echo $res;//$res:"replacement hello world replacement"
```

I want replace only the last '}        }'using preg_replace()

Comment: http://pp9fysgz4.bkt.clouddn.com/QQ%E5%9B%BE%E7%89%8720190429153106.png

Comment: http://pp9fysgz4.bkt.clouddn.com/QQ%E5%9B%BE%E7%89%8720190429153110.png

Comment: Is $text and $ss two different patterns that you combine? One has `/` delimiter the other `~`? Or is that real `/` in $text?

Comment: / is a  mistake i have delete but it still not work

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/XJRRos/2

Comment: omg thks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the last to occurrences of `}` with only whitespace chars between them using:

```
}\s*}(?![^}]*})$
```

- `}\s*}` Match `}`, 0+ whitespace chars, then `}`
- `(?![^}]*})` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right are no more occurrences of `]`
- `$` Assert end of the string

Note that this does not take balances parenthesis into account, just the last to `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kkS4ov/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $content="}}hello world}}";
    $text='}\s*[\r\n]*\s*[\r\n]*\s*}';
    $ss="~$text(?!.*$text)~";
    $res=preg_replace($ss,'replacement',$content);
    print_r($res);exit;
```

Output:

```
   }}hello worldreplacement
```